# Eclipse plugin for spring Boot

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

I am going to create a small web application using spring boot and maven in Eclipse. I am new to spring boot ,

Is there any Eclipse plugin available for creating spring boot application  like STS?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [STS for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse) from `Help` > `Eclipse Market Place....` on Eclipse.

Comment: Does STS supports Spring boot also ?